# I think MySqli select is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I think I must be going crazy because my MySqli select code isn't working.

Any Ideas why please?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *
FROM `table` WHERE `auto` = 1 LIMIT 0 , 30");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$updateid = $row['id'];
}

echo $updateid;
```

I am not getting any error messages but the while statement is not triggering for some reason. A row with auto with value 1 does exist.

Comment: To check , Gary please use `print_r($row);` in `while`

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this error now.

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in........

Comment: check the mysqli docs here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: You could also use something like this: `$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);` in order to see how many rows are returned from your query. If you are not getting errors and are also not getting any results, look over your SQL to make sure it is accurate. In addition, always use error checking as stated above to make sure that every step is being executed OK. You can test SQL very easily in a program such as "MySQL Workbench" to make sure the SQL its self is returning results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also encountered the same problem earlier, try using mysql instead of mysqli. mysqli may not be working because of the version of XAMPP that you are using(older version does not support its use).

Comment: This could be the issue, because mysqli is a "newer" thing to PHP

Comment: Yes, that is probably the issue. I faced the same problem a couple of months back and when i replaced mysqli with mysql then it worked out fine.